# Output location in ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, modelbuilder, file-geodatabase

I am creating a model where the first step is creating a geodatabase with location and name set as parameters. After that I created another step (Table to Table) to import a single table to the created GDB. After that, this table is going through many steps and tools where I have many outputs afterwards.

How I can assign the location of the many outputs produced to be in the created GDB at the beginning?

I tried the "%" sign but it didn't work. If the "%" is the solution, please give me an example on how to use it correctly.

I am using ArcGIS 10.2.2 for Desktop.

Comment: Please could you show a screenshot of how you used the % sign?  If the box coming out of your "Create FileGeodatabase" tool is called "Outputs", then all you need to do in the "Output" field in any other tools is have %Outputs%\Dataset    Where %Outputs% references the database you created and "Dataset" is the name you want to give to the dataset you are creating.

Comment: Thanks Dan! I didn't use it in the way you described it. I will try your suggestion and see what will happen. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"If the box coming out of your "Create FileGeodatabase" tool is called "Outputs", then all you need to do in the "Output" field in any other tools is have %Outputs%\Dataset Where %Outputs% references the database you created and "Dataset" is the name you want to give to the dataset you are creating"

Thanks to Dan_h_b ( https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/21054/dan-h-b )for the solution. I couldn't mark his reply as an a answer so I just copied and paste his reply.